# Uncaught ReferenceError: set_metadata is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I'm using the Yummly API (https://developer.yummly.com/documentation) and I am trying to parse a JSONP list of courses to use in a drop-down box. The format of the file I am requesting (located at http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/metadata/course?_app_id=[My App ID]&_app_key=[My App Key]) is:

```
set_metadata('course', [{"id":"course-Main Dishes","type":"course","description":"Main Dishes","searchValue":"course^course-Main Dishes"},....................}])
```

The request seems to work fine, and I can view the results in the Network tab in Chrome. However, in the console I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: set_metadata is not defined" I've done a lot of looking around, and have found people with similar but different errors, but I have not understood the cause or why the fixes for their errors work. I am fairly new to jQuery, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong with my request, which is:

```
var coursesURL = 'http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/metadata/course?_app_id=' + appID + '&_app_key=' + appKey;
var courses = [];

//Query for the list
$.getJSON(coursesURL + '?callback=?', null, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    //Go through each result object found
    $.each(data.course, function(i, course) {
        courses.push(course.description);
    });
    console.log(courses);
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I would also really appreciate an explanation of what I am missing, not just the fix. Thank you.

Comment: try `$.ajax({
    url: coursesURL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        //
    }
})`

Answer (score 1):

The reasons I'm adding this as an answer and not a comment are because i don't have enough reputation to comment and this is the only thing i can find on the yummly api returning jsonp.

I was able to get past the "uncaught referenceError" problem but now its only returning the word 'allergy', which is in the response, and I'm not getting the rest of the data.

here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"//api.yummly.com/v1/api/metadata/allergy?_app_id=[APP_ID]&_app_key=[APP_KEY]?callback=",
        dataType:"jsonp",
        jsonpCallback:"set_metadata",
        beforeSend:function(){
            console.log("sending");
        },
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("send error and returned:");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

here is the response:

```
set_metadata('allergy', [

    {"id":"392","shortDescription":"Wheat-Free","longDescription":"Wheat-Free","searchValue":"392^Wheat-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]},

    {"id":"393","shortDescription":"Gluten-Free","longDescription":"Gluten-Free","searchValue":"393^Gluten-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]},

    {"id":"394","shortDescription":"Peanut-Free","longDescription":"Peanut-Free","searchValue":"394^Peanut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]},

    {"id":"395","shortDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","longDescription":"Tree Nut-Free","searchValue":"395^Tree Nut-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]},

    {"id":"396","shortDescription":"Dairy-Free","longDescription":"Dairy-Free","searchValue":"396^Dairy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]},

    {"id":"397","shortDescription":"Egg-Free","longDescription":"Egg-Free","searchValue":"397^Egg-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]},

    {"id":"398","shortDescription":"Seafood-Free","longDescription":"Seafood-Free","searchValue":"398^Seafood-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]},

    {"id":"399","shortDescription":"Sesame-Free","longDescription":"Sesame-Free","searchValue":"399^Sesame-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]},

    {"id":"400","shortDescription":"Soy-Free","longDescription":"Soy-Free","searchValue":"400^Soy-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]},

    {"id":"401","shortDescription":"Sulfite-Free","longDescription":"Sulfite-Free","searchValue":"401^Sulfite-Free","type":"allergy","localesAvailableIn":["en-US","en-GB"]}

]);
```

the line of code that says:

```
jsonpCallback:"set_metadata",
```

in the ajax call gets me past the reference error but im not getting the rest of the data that's in the response.

please help?
Finbar

Comment: You should ask this as it's own question (and link to this question if you want). That way you can start to build reputation. Once you do that edit your post with the link to the question and I'll try and help you out there!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

JSONP is returning not JSON text, but a function to the callback. Thus, I needed a function in my code called "set_metadata" that is used upon success of the json/ajax call.

Specifically, I defined function

```
function set_metadata(course, data) {
    //Do stuff here
};
```

I tested it and that correctly captures the data I am trying to get.